# Creating a Custom Speech Recognition in IONIC

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, speech-recognition

I want to create a speech to text application that recognizes a Visayan language(a group of languages in the Philippines), I know there are already speech recognition plugins in IONIC but unfortunately, it doesn't support this language. Any idea or suggestions on how to integrate a customize speech recognition that could both run in android and IOS platforms?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Google Cloud Platform Speech to Text API which supports Filipino https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages. But it's not free you need to pay as per usage.

Here are the list of client libraries supported

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries